# Unasked Mojarra initializing

Tags: jsf, tomcat7, tapestry, mojarra

I'm using Tapestry 5.3 framework in my Java 1.7 web-app, and run in under Tomcat 7.x.

Suddenly today I've found in startup logs of my app these lines:

```
jul 31, 2014 12:12:46 PM com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener contextInitialized
INFO: Initializing Mojarra 2.2.7 ( 20140610-1547 https://svn.java.net/svn/mojarra~svn/tags/2.2.7@13362) for context '/XXX'
jul 31, 2014 12:12:46 PM com.sun.faces.spi.InjectionProviderFactory createInstance
INFO: JSF1048: PostConstruct/PreDestroy annotations present.  ManagedBeans methods marked with these annotations will have said annotations processed.
```

I have never seen these log-lines before in my app. Furthermore, "Initializing Mojarra" process takes some appreciable time.

So I should think, that somebody among our project developers have added special libraries - but there aren't any JSF or Faces libraries in the build.

I have no ideas what have changed and how I can cut out Mojarra from my project? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in `jsf-*.jar` libraries placed mistakenly in `/lib` folder of Tomcat. They were initialized due to tomcat startup. Removing them solved the problem.